# Is It Possible for Two Applications to Create a Memory Mapped File with the Same Name?

Tags: c#, memory-mapped-files

I read on MSDN

> A memory-mapped file contains the contents of a file in virtual memory. This mapping between a file and memory space enables an application, including multiple processes, to modify the file by reading and writing directly to the memory.

**Source:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/memory-mapped-files

And on another forum:

> Memory-mapped files can be shared across multiple processes. Processes can map to the same memory-mapped file by using a common name that is assigned by the process that created the file.

What would happen if I create two memory mapped files using `MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile` from two different applications, and assign them the same name? Will this throw an exception?

Answer (score 1):

After testing this I found that an exception is thrown:

```
Unhandled exception. System.IO.IOException: Cannot create a file when that file already exists.
   at System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.MemoryMappedFile.CreateCore(FileStream fileStream, String mapName, HandleInheritability inheritability, MemoryMappedFileAccess access, MemoryMappedFileOptions options, Int64 capacity)
   at System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(String path, FileMode mode, String mapName, Int64 capacity, MemoryMappedFileAccess access)
   at LiveFileReader.AsyncLiveFileReader..ctor(String filePath) in ...
```

Comment: If you want the two applications to share one, it seems like this would work: [MemoryMappedFile.CreateOrOpen()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile.createoropen?view=netcore-3.1)